# Badge notification doesn't appear

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, achievements-dialog

This morning when I opened my Stack Overflow account, I have seen my badge number increase (+ 1 Quorum Badge), but I have searched in my notifications, and there is no notification. Is it normal for this badge or is it a new rule?

Comment: Certain badges do not give notifications once you have a minimum rep level *anywhere in the network*. See [The new notification system didn't notify me of my Investor badge :(](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/133556); you are considered a veteran now.

Comment: Even in the `achievements` ?!?

Comment: *Specifically* in achievements.